# OptimizeWarning from SciPy's optimize_curve can't be fixed

Tags: python, scipy, data-modeling, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a set (in my case the total cumulative number of cases) of data regarding the currently spreading virus using SciPy's optimize_curve. As we would expect, the initial data grows exponentially as shows my the following graph: [image: Data showing virus evolution] ------> (Red-deaths , yellow - currently active cases, blue - recovers , green scatter - currently home isolated).
Of course we are expecting that there would be a peak in total cases in the first place, and then see the graph grow logarithmically. This behavior is well described by a sigmoid function  [image: Sigmoid Function] to which I added parameters a,b,c such that the fit would turn out a bit more precise by defining the functions [image: Eq1] or [image: Eq2].
The thing I cannot understand is that using the first sigmoid function, it allowed me to draw the fit with a few parameters (otherwise giving me: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated, category=OptimizeWarning), while for the second sigmoid function it gives me the error for any parameter. I also tried some other sigmoid-like functions such as tanh(b+cx) and the error function, but also raises the same warning for every parameter. The functions are all vectorized using Numpy's `np.vectorize(function)` in order to input a list instead.

```py
def FitSigmoidea(x,a,b,c):
    return a * math.exp(b+c*x) / 1+math.exp(b+c*x)
def FitError(x,a,b,c):
    return a*math.erf(b*(x-c))
def FitHypTan(x,a,b,c):
    return a*math.tanh(b*(x-c))

MyFitSigmoidea = np.vectorize(FitSigmoidea)
init_par_sigmo = [10,-83,4]
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(MyFitSigmoidea, days , bars , p0 = init_par_sigmo)
#days is a python list from 1 to 35, bars is a python list of total virus cases
plt.plot(days,MyFitSigmoidea(days,params[0],params[1],params[2]),color='#F000FF' ,label = 'Sigmoid Fit')
```

Why is this error raised every time? Thanks in advance to everyone who helps!

Comment: Numpy already provides vectorial functions like `np.exp` and `np.tanh`, so there's no need to use python's math module and vectorize them on your own. I guess providing the data makes it easier to help.

Comment: ...hi, using only the numpy functions I do not see any difference when using form 1 or 2 of your first sigmoid and applying it to ther german covid19 case data.  Hint: `MyFitSigmoidea( days, *params )` should work in `plot`